# How to prevent timer reset when ViewController transition

Tags: ios, timer

I am running a timer in my `ViewController A` as my main View Controller.
The timer is initialized in `viewDidLoad()` as following:

```
var timer = CustomizedTimer()
```

and it start to count down from 15 minutes.

When user swift from `ViewController A` to `SettingViewController`, the timer reset to 15 minutes again.

I try to put the timer instance into `AppDelegate`, it does not work.
What I need to do is, keep the timer working in background whenever User switch view controller.
So, how to fix this?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a singleton class to hold your `Timer`, but also, if you push from `ViewController A` to `SettingViewController`, the first vc wont get deinit, and your timer will still running, or you are creating the timer in `viewWillAppear` or later then it will get created again, thus reset your Timer

Sample:

```
class TimerHelper {
    static let shared = TimerHelper()
    var timer: Timer!
}
```

Call it like:

```
TimerHelper.shared.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
    print("a")
})
```

Replace the block with target based is also fine, point it to your main class to execute code

Comment: I have heard a lot about the singleton class, I know it is a design pattern. I have tried to do this. But I did not have a clue about it at all even though I follow a few tutorials. Would u mind show me how to do it in code? I am pretty new in programming :) thanks

Comment: I think its pretty easy to find around here, quite simple to make one, also should check again if you create Timer on your viewWillAppear or not, so move it to viewDidLoad and see if it got reset

Comment: Working on that now

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i can not give you a full example, but maybe you can use Threads to achieve the behavior.